# changing during accomplish query

Tags: php, mysql

I've such a interested question for me , please if anyone know answer me .

---

So I have two table , in first i have column named "num" which includes (like say phone numbers) and in second table i have column "sec_num" which also includes some of the exactly same numbers like in first table from column "num" and second column named "persons" (from second table also)

I am retrieving data from first table and i want that if first table phone numbers (from num column) matched to second table numbers (from column "sec_num") then retrieved value from "persons" column. Is it possible to do ? if yes , please help me , Thanks ...

PS. if it is necessary to know i am using php, but I think this job must do sql

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question right a regular left join should do the trick;

```
select num, persons from first left join second on num=sec_num;
```

Answer (score 1):

If we call the tables `tableA` (first table) and `tableB` (second table) thern a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.num = tableB.sec_num
```

should do the trick.